# How to optimise price comparison app (Flutter), so that only one http.get has to be called at a time?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm working on a price comparison app that compares the prices of a few indonesian e-commerce websites. Some uses html some uses api. It looks like this:
[image]

The github repo is here:
https://github.com/0n9aldrin/price-comparison

Ignoring the wrong rating stars, everything else works fine. However, the app is very laggy. As you can see at the bottom of the screen, I also display the total products of that search and I noticed that every time I search an item, all the different tabs make http.get requests all at the same time just to get the total at the bottom of the pages (future builder) and then when I click on the individual tab, it makes another request to display the gridview. There are possibly two options that come to my mind:

1. Load all the websites all at once, so the app will be laggy only for a few seconds and then everything will be better afterwards.
2. Load the information only when I click on the next tab. Currently, it does this only for the gridview but not the future builder on the bottom of the page.

These are two ideas that I came up with, but I have no idea how to implement. Looking at my repo is there a way to implement either one of these ideas? If the lagginess is not caused by the http requests please give suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a "FutureBuilder" for each TAB_PAGE. When a user goes to another screen it loads only if it is not in the cache.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm not sure where to insert the future builder

Comment: Look this article https://codetober.com/flutter-provider-examples/ using FutureProvider can help you.

Comment: In addition to this, you might want to look into pagination. It looks like you are loading all 100k+ results at the same time. Pagination allows you to load them as the user scrolls.